# Master Detail with SQLite. Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, master-detail

I am studying a Master Detail Flow with SQLite Tutorial . I have not finished my app cause I have to make another things such like communication between fragments. My app is working good in smartphone emulator until now. Then, when I tried to run app in tablet, there is appearing this in logcat.

```
07-04 00:39:45.049 4373-4373/codigofacilito.applistacompras E/AndroidRuntime: 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: codigofacilito.applistacompras, PID: 4373
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{codigofacilito.applistacompras/codigofacilito.applistacompras.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: listas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM listas
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
    at codigofacilito.applistacompras.Helpers.DataBaseHelper.fetchAlllist(DataBaseHelper.java:264)
    at codigofacilito.applistacompras.Fragments.ListaFragment.onCreateView(ListaFragment.java:48)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1507)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1303)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1502)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1737)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3512)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at codigofacilito.applistacompras.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
07-04 00:39:45.049 4373-4373/codigofacilito.applistacompras E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is my code

**activity_main(sw600dp)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:name="codigofacilito.applistacompras.Fragments.ListaFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:context="codigofacilito.applistacompras.Fragments.ListaFragment"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package codigofacilito.applistacompras.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import codigofacilito.applistacompras.Fragments.ItemsFragment;
import codigofacilito.applistacompras.Interfaces.CallBacks;
import codigofacilito.applistacompras.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBacks{
public boolean mTwoPane;
private static final String ELEMENTS_TAG = "ELEMENTS";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(findViewById(R.id.list_item) != null){
        mTwoPane = true;

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.list_item, new ItemsFragment(), 
        ELEMENTS_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }else {
            mTwoPane = false;
        }
    }
}

public boolean getmTwoPane(){
    return this.mTwoPane;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(String nombreLista, String lista) {
    if(mTwoPane){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("nombreLista",nombreLista);
        bundle.putString("lista",lista);
        ItemsFragment itemsFragment = new ItemsFragment();
        itemsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.list_item,itemsFragment).
                commit();

    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemList.class);
        intent.putExtra("nombreLista",nombreLista);
        intent.putExtra("lista",lista);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

**DataBaseHelper**

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = 
"/data/data/codigofacilito.applistacompras/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "bdlistas.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;


public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

 public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db_read = null;

    if(dbExist){

    }else{
        db_read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db_read.close();
        try{
            copyDataBase();
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new Error("Error copiando base de datos");
        }
    }
}

public boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    String myPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
        return  dbFile.exists();
    }

    if(checkDB != null)
        checkDB.close();

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;

}

    private void copyDataBase() throws  IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    /*int length;

    while((length = myInput.read()) != -1){
        myOutput.write(length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();*/

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;

    while((length = myInput.read(buffer))!= -1){
        if(length > 0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = 
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

public synchronized void close(){

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    //COLOCAR CODIGO SQL PARA CREAR BD
    try{
        createDataBase();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    //CODIGO DE LA ACTUALIZACIÓN
}

public Cursor fetchAlllist() throws SQLException{

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM listas",null);

    if(cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it!.

Comment: try reinstalling app in your device. I think your present database is not updating in device. So whenever your code tries to a access a db Column which is existed in db in emulator ..app works.

Comment: Thank you my friend!!. It works!. :)